# Can i wait for sqlite lock to be released on the cli?

Tags: sqlite, thread-safety, locking, command-line-interface

I have a sqlite3 database file that multiple processes access simultaneously via the sqlite3 command utility from shell scripts.

This sometimes causes some `database is locked` kind of errors when writing.

The thing is I don't have any performance concern, but I would simply want for each query to block until the database gets unlocked, and then do its job. Right now it just fails, so the only way would be to catch the failure and keep retrying.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I checked the documentation about [thread safety with sqlite](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) and it basically says that the *serialized* mode is the most "thread friendly". When checking the compile options

```sh
echo 'pragma compile_options' | sqlite3 db.db | grep -i threadsafe
```

I get `THREADSAFE=1` which is indeed serialized (the default).

here is a sample script to demonstrate the problem:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

rm -f db.db

echo 'CREATE TABLE animals (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  name varchar
)' | sqlite3 db.db

echo "insert into animals(name) values('rabbit')" | sqlite3 db.db &
echo "insert into animals(name) values('rabbit')" | sqlite3 db.db &
echo "insert into animals(name) values('rabbit')" | sqlite3 db.db &
echo "insert into animals(name) values('rabbit')" | sqlite3 db.db &
echo "insert into animals(name) values('rabbit')" | sqlite3 db.db &
```

The output is something like

```
Error: near line 1: database is locked
Error: near line 1: database is locked
Error: near line 1: database is locked
```

And barely 2 animals out of 5 got inserted. I would just want every query to succeed, even it takes a bit more time because of the requests queuing up.

---

sqlite3 version 3.22.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sqlite3 shell's `.timeout` command can be used to specify the number of milliseconds to [wait while trying to open a locked database](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) before giving an error. So try changing your script to use it; something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# A 1 second busy timeout
timeout=1000

rm -f db.db

sqlite3 db.db <<EOF
CREATE TABLE animals (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  name text
);
EOF

sqlite3 db.db <<EOF &
.timeout $timeout
insert into animals(name) values('rabbit 1');
EOF

sqlite3 db.db <<EOF &
.timeout $timeout
insert into animals(name) values('rabbit 2');
EOF

sqlite3 db.db <<EOF &
.timeout $timeout
insert into animals(name) values('rabbit 3');
EOF

sqlite3 db.db <<EOF &
.timeout $timeout
insert into animals(name) values('rabbit 4');
EOF
```

Note the use of [heredocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), instead of using `echo`. They come in handy when sending non-trivial amounts of literal text to a processes standard input in a script.

This also has nothing to do with threads; those are all separate processes, not threads.

Comment: Yes, it works and this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @Shawn! One can also use `sqlite3 -cmd '.timeout 1000' db.db ` to separate session configuration from the query itself.

Comment: If you're executing a simple command you can skip the heredoc like so: `sqlite3 db.db ".timeout 5000;" ".dump"`